# T-SQL Select duplicate rows where at least 1 column has a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table as follows:

```
ProductDetails
-----------------
ProductDetailsID int
ProductIdentifier VARCHAR (20)
ProductID int
ProductFile VARCHAR(255)
ProductAvailability char(2)
RightsCountry varchar(MAX)
Deleted bit
```

There was a bug in the platform recently that allowed a large number of duplicates in. So I could have multiple ProductDetails entries which are the same EXCEPT for the ProductDetailsID (PK) and ProductFile (this is null, for some reason the duplicates didn't insert the files).

I need to write a T-SQL script that finds these duplicates with a view to deleting them (after examination).

I have found this online, which is great. It gives me the ProductIdentifier with several records, and the number of duplicates.

```
SELECT pd.ProductIdentifier, COUNT(pd.ProductIdentifier) AS NumOccurrences
FROM dbo.ProductDetails pd
GROUP BY pd.ProductIdentifier
HAVING ( COUNT(pd.ProductIdentifier) > 1 )
```

The thing is, some of these records should remain. I need to select the ProductDetail records that have duplicate ProductIdentifiers, where at least 1 of the duplicates has a FileName and all other columns are exactly the same. For example, if I have a dataset as follows:

```
ProductDetailsID | ProductIdentifier | ProductID | ProductFile | ProductAvailability | RightsCountry | Deleted
123 | 567890 | 12 | filename.png | 20 | AU CX CC CK HM NZ NU NF TK | 0
124 | 567890 | 12 | (NULL) | 20 | AU CX CC CK HM NZ NU NF TK | 0
125 | 567890 | 12 | (NULL) | 20 | AU CX CC CK HM NZ NU NF TK | 0
```

I need to return ProductDetailsID 124 and 125 as these are for deletion. I'd appreciate any guidance or links to examples or any help at all!

Comment: "at least 1 of the duplicates has a FileName" - what if more than 1 of the duplicates has a filename? Will they always match (or, if the rows match on all values except the filename, are they not considered duplicates)?

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever There could be more than 1 of the duplicates with a filename. I don't want to delete (select) any record with a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works and is a cheeky way of abusing the partitioned window functions:

```
declare @ProductDetails table(
ProductDetailsID int not null,
ProductIdentifier VARCHAR(20) not null,
ProductID int not null,
ProductFile VARCHAR(255) null,
ProductAvailability char(2) not null,
RightsCountry varchar(MAX) not null,
Deleted bit not null
)

insert into @ProductDetails(ProductDetailsID,ProductIdentifier,ProductID,
             ProductFile,ProductAvailability,RightsCountry,Deleted) values
(123,567890,12,'filename.png',20,'AU CX CC CK HM NZ NU NF TK',0),
(124,567890,12,NULL,20,'AU CX CC CK HM NZ NU NF TK',0),
(125,567890,12,NULL,20,'AU CX CC CK HM NZ NU NF TK',0)

;With FillInFileNames as (
    select *,
    MAX(ProductFile) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductIdentifier,ProductID,
                                    ProductAvailability,RightsCountry,Deleted)
       as AnyFileName
    from @ProductDetails
)
select * from FillInFileNames
where ProductFile is null and AnyFileName is not null
```

And the fact that aggregate functions will never return `NULL` if at least one input value wasn't `NULL`.

Result:

```
ProductDetailsID ProductIdentifier    ProductID   ProductFile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ProductAvailability RightsCountry                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Deleted AnyFileName
---------------- -------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
124              567890               12          NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            20                  AU CX CC CK HM NZ NU NF TK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0       filename.png
125              567890               12          NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            20                  AU CX CC CK HM NZ NU NF TK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0       filename.png
```

---

It may also be instructive for the OP to observe that the top of my script isn't *much* more than the table information and sample data provided in their question - except mine is actually runnable.

It might be worth considering writing your samples in such a style in the future, because that way it can be immediately copy & pasted from your question into a query window.

Comment: Thanks Damien, will take your advice onboard for future questions :) Thanks for the good answer !

Answer (score 1):

```
create view rows_to_delete
as
select *
from (
    select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by ProductIdentifier order by ProductFile desc, ProductDetailsID) as rn
    from t
) x
where rn > 1
and ProductFile is null
```

Comment: The OP has since clarified that there may be multiple rows with non-`NULL` `ProductFile` values and all of them should be preserved.

Comment: Unfortunatelly only after I've posted the answer. OK, added another condition to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

The following query first gets the counts and then filters those records whose fields match with the entry with the fileName.

```
WITH counts as
(
SELECT 
    ProductDetailsID
    , ProductIdentifier
    , ProductID 
    , ProductFile 
    , ProductAvailability 
    , RightsCountry 
    , Deleted
    , COUNT(*) as cnt_files
FROM
    dbo.ProductDetails pd
GROUP BY 
    ProductDetailsID
    , ProductIdentifier
    , ProductID 
    , ProductFile 
    , ProductAvailability 
    , RightsCountry 
    , Deleted
)
SELECT
    c1.*
FROM
    counts c1
INNER JOIN counts c2
ON c1.ProductIdentifier = c2.ProductIdentifier
AND c1.ProductID = c2.ProductID
AND c1.ProductFile = c2.ProductFile
AND c1.ProductAvailability = c2.ProductAvailability
AND c1.RightsCountry = c2.RightsCountry
AND c1.Deleted = c2.Deleted
WHERE ProductFile is NULL;
```